# Error : Library "IEEE" does not contain primary unit "numeric_std_unsigned"

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm using Quartus prime edition v15.1 for writing a register file and I need to use the `numeric_std_unsigned` package. On compiling, there's an error saying

> Error (10481): VHDL Use Clause error : design library "IEEE" does not contain primary unit "NUMERIC_STD_unsigned". Verify that the primary unit exists in the library and has been successfully compiled.

How doesn't the IEEE library have the `numeric_std_unsigned` package? I've searched a lot and found that IEEE actually supports it. And if so, how can I firstly download the package and install it to the compiler or add it to my project?

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std_unsigned.all;


entity regfile is
  port( clk: in STD_LOGIC;
        regwrite: in STD_LOGIC; 
        rs, rt, rd: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); 
        data_in: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0); 
        rd1, rd2: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)); 
end;

architecture behave of regfile is 
  type registerFile is array (3 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
  signal registers: registerFile;
begin 
  process(clk) begin

    if rising_edge(clk) then 
      if regwrite='1' then
        registers(to_integer(unsigned(rd))) <= data_in; 
      end if;
     end if;
  end process;

  process(all)
  begin
    if (to_integer(rs)=0) 
    then rd1 <= X"0000"; 
    else rd1 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(rs))); 
    end if;

    if (to_integer(rt)=0) 
    then rd2 <= X"0000";
    else rd2 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(rt)));
    end if;
  end process; 
end;
```

When I use `IEEE.numeric_std_unsigned.all` the compiler reports the error I posted above.

And when I use `IEEE_numeric_std.all` the compiler reports

1. can't determine type of object at  `to_integer`
2. more than one `Use` Clause imports a declaration of simple name `unsigned` -- none of the declarations are directly visible

Comment: A VHDL primary unit is either an entity, a package declaration or a configuration. `numeric_std_unsigned` is a package name associated with both a package declaration and it's associated package body found in the IEEE library in -2008 compliant implementations. You're likely missing something to tell your tool to use -2008 resources. Alternatively you could use type conversions between std_logic_vector, etc. and unsigned.

Comment: @user1155120
I didn't miss it. I chose vhdl-2008 version in compiler settings  the first time i used my tool. How can i use those type conversions ?

Comment: Which Quartus version are you using? I have checked my installation of (the rather old) Quartus 13.1 here, and it seems **not** to include a `numeric_std_unsigned` package. Please note, that VHDL'08 support is often incomplete in synthesis compilers.

Comment: @Martin Zabel I'm using 15.1.  Yes i found out that it supports only few features regarding VHDL'08, even Vivado also doesn't fully support it. only synplify adopt almost all of it...Anyways, the code is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Once you edited your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the error is clearly visible.

Remove the use clause with std_logic_arith, it's incompatible with the unsigned declaration package numeric_std_unsigned uses (referenced from a use clause invoking ieee.numeric_std.all).  In it's place use

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

Some of the `to_integer` function calls found in your `regfile` architecture have a signature of [STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR return NATURAL].

(STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR is the base type for resolved subtype STD_LOGIC_VECTOR in package std_logic_1164 in VHDL -2008).

Some `to_integer` conversion function calls (e.g. `to_integer(rs)`) require package numeric_std_unsigned.

Those depending on package numeric_std  (e.g. `registers(to_integer(unsigned(rs)))` also depend on a visible declaration for type unsigned being the same as the type declaration of the same name being visible in package numeric_std (referenced in a use clause in package numeric_std_unsigned).

In VHDL each declaration is unique even if they have the same name. Which one you are referencing is governed by visibility rules.

Before changing the use clause only the unsigned type declared in the Synopsys package was visible in your entity and architecture pair.

After switching std_logic_arith to numeric_std your code analyzes with a -2008 compliant VHDL implementation:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 
-- use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity regfile is
    port ( 
        clk:        in  STD_LOGIC;
        regwrite:   in  STD_LOGIC; 
        rs, rt, rd: in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); 
        data_in:    in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0); 
        rd1, rd2:   out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
    ); 
end entity;

architecture behave of regfile is 
    type registerFile is array (3 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal registers: registerFile;
begin 
    process (clk) 
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then 
            if regwrite = '1' then
                registers(to_integer(unsigned(rd))) <= data_in; 
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (all)
    begin
        if to_integer(rs) = 0 then 
            rd1 <= X"0000"; 
        else 
            rd1 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(rs))); 
        end if;

        if to_integer(rt) = 0 then 
            rd2 <= X"0000";
        else 
            rd2 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(rt)));
        end if;
    end process; 
end architecture;
```

Style changes not withstanding the only change is the use clause.

You could remove the dependency on package numeric_std by changing the to_integer function calls with the signature [UNSIGNED return NATURAL] to [STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR return NATURAL]:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
-- use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity regfile is
    port ( 
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        regwrite:   in  std_logic; 
        rs, rt, rd: in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 
        data_in:    in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
        rd1, rd2:   out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
    ); 
end entity;

architecture behave of regfile is 
    type registerFile is array (3 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal registers: registerFile;
begin 
    process (clk) 
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then 
            if regwrite = '1' then
                registers(to_integer(rd)) <= data_in; 
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (all)
    begin
        if to_integer(rs) = 0 then 
            rd1 <= X"0000"; 
        else 
            rd1 <= registers(to_integer(rs)); 
        end if;

        if to_integer(rt) = 0 then 
            rd2 <= X"0000";
        else 
            rd2 <= registers(to_integer(rt));
        end if;
    end process; 
end architecture;
```

Note we've gotten rid of the use clause with package numeric_std and dropped some type conversions for generating the indexes for indexed names selecting `registers` elements for writes to the register file as well as both read ports.

Both these modifications to your code example analyze, elaborate and simulate telling us the indexes work correctly. The second one using only package numeric_std_unsigned enhances readability.

And of course if your VHDL tool is actually missing package numeric_std_unsigned and it isn't cured by re-installation or updating the Quartus tools you could use a -1993 compliant design description:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
-- use IEEE.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity regfile is
    port (
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        regwrite:   in  std_logic;
        rs, rt, rd: in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        data_in:    in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        rd1, rd2:   out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of regfile is 
    type registerFile is array (3 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal registers: registerFile;
begin
    process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if regwrite = '1' then
                registers(to_integer(unsigned(rd))) <= data_in;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (rs, rt) -- (all)
    begin
        if to_integer(unsigned(rs)) = 0 then
            rd1 <= X"0000";
        else
            rd1 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(rs)));
        end if;

        if to_integer(unsigned(rt)) = 0 then
            rd2 <= X"0000";
        else
            rd2 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(rt)));
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Where the process sensitivity list is manually specified and all to_integer calls are from package numeric_std, requiring unsigned type conversions for std_logic_vector values.

(And this analyzes, elaborates and simulates).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, yes i was going to tell you that I still don't have `numeric_std_unsigned`, but after the edit and placing `unsigned` before every `rs` `rt` `rd`, everything got okay and the project compiled without errors

Comment: Section 16.8.5.1 of the VHDL'08 Std. states that _The four packages [numeric_std, numeric_std_unsigned, numeric_bit, and numeric_bit_unsigned] are mutually incompatible, and only one shall be used in any given design unit._ Thus, your first example would be not compliant, or?

Comment: 16.8.5 Packages for arithmetic using bit and standard logic values is from IEEE Std 1076.3-1997, 7. Standard arithmetic packages, which states "The *two* packages are mutually incompatible, and only one shall be used in any given design unit. ..." (numeric_bit/numeric_std). While numeric_std and numeric_std_unsigned are not mutually exclusive containing no homographs not resolved by the context of overload resolution (other than the copyright notice). The change to *four* is inaccurate, simplistic and not supported by LCS 2006-102 which specifies *two*. Also see LCS 2006-125.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the `unsigned` type of the `numeric_std` package in the `ieee` library.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
signal foo : unsigned(7 downto 0);
```

or

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numric_std;
...
signal bar : numeric_std.unsigned(7 downto 0);
```

Comment: Please see the question's edit.
 
When i tried using  `Ieee_numeric_std` it says
 1-can't determine type of object at  `to_integer`
 2-more than one Use Clause imports a declaration of simple name `unsigned` -- none of the declarations are directly visible

Comment: Nowhere in this question is Ieee_numeric_std mentioned but ieee.numeric_std. Don't replace dots with underscores in VHDL - that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The installation folder of Quartus Prime 15.1 actually contains a file called `numeric_std_unsigned_vhdl2008.vhd` which defines the package  `numeric_std_unsigned` and its body. But, apparently the synthesizer does not support it.

The [Quartus Prime Standard Handbook v15.1.1](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/qts/archives/qts-qps-handbook-15.1.1.pdf), Volume 1 gives in Section 16 under "VHDL Synthesis Support" -> "VHDL-2008 Support" a link to [this online help page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_list_2008_vhdl_support.htm). At the time of writing this answer, the list of supported VHDL'08 features does **not** reference Section 16.8.5 of the VHDL'08 Standard which defines the package `numeric_std_unsigned`. There is also no reference to Appendix A.2.4.

The following sub-section in the Quartus manual states further:

> The Quartus Prime software includes the standard IEEE libraries and several vendor-specific VHDL libraries.
>
> The IEEE library includes the standard VHDL packages std_logic_1164, numeric_std, numeric_bit, and math_real.

Given that, you must revert back to using the `numeric_std` package. But, this package defines the type `unsigned` which is also defined in `std_logic_arith`. You should **not** use the non-standard `std_logic_arith` package from Synopsys anymore.

Thus, you have to use the package `numeric_std` instead of both `numeric_std_unsigned` and `std_logic_arith.`. Then you have to convert all `std_logic_vector` to `unsigned` first, before passing them as an argument to the function `to_integer`, e.g.:

```
to_integer(unsigned(rs))
```

instead of

```
to_integer(rs)
```